# Click on button until alert is present in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium

I want to click a button until a javascript alert is present.

Here is what I would like to do:

```
while(!ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent())
  button.click();
```

But this does not work as the expression is not evaluated to a boolean condition.

I have tried:

```
while(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent() == null)
  button.click();
```

But this results in never going into the loop. Thanks for any guidance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The predicate `ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent` cannot be evaluated directly in a `while`.
You can use it with a waiter:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());
```

But in your case a better choice would be to implement a predicate that clicks on the button until the alert is present:

```
WebElement button = driver.findElement(By.id("..."));

// clicks on the button every 100ms until the alert is present
Alert alert = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20, 100).until((WebDriver drv)->{
    try{
        button.click();
        return drv.switchTo().alert();
    }catch(NoAlertPresentException ex){
        return null;
    }
});

// accept the alert
alert.accept();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can go with this workaround:-

```
while(alert.getClass().getCanonicalName().toString().equals("org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.RemoteAlert")){
button.click();
}
```